# Best way to display list of options

Tags: lists, options, many-options

There's a page that has a list of options like below

- 002-12345
- 002-16516
- 003-21565
- 008-15168
- 001-86841

Currently, we display it inside a box and user has to scroll up or down to select whichever account they wish. Though this can be overwhelming if the user has 10,000 accounts, then there can be 100-200 pages of account lists like this. If the user has to select 005, they need to scroll through 10 pages to get to that. Well, we can ask the user to make some favorite and show those first then show rest in the list, that's an improvement for quick selection but no other idea comes to my mind. Is there any suggestion you guys have?

I attached how it looks currently in a picture.

[image]

Edit:
@Mike M asked some great questions so I added below information:
Desktop, user clicks on one of the accounts in this list and we load some statement for that account on the page. Table selection only it has account number and name columns, there's also a search functionality users can search accounts too, this table makes it easier to select ideally.

Comment: is this desktop, mobile? What do the users do with this information, is it for selection only, or does the table also indicate status? 
Do users use the account number to look up and select, or are there other properties they already have in mind? Showing us the larger context will help to get more answers from the community...

Comment: Desktop, user clicks on one of the accounts in this list and we load some statement for that account on the page. Table selection only it has account number and name columns, there's also a search functionality yes users can search accounts too, this table makes it easier to select ideally, thank you Mike for your feedback.

Comment: Welcome to uxsx!

Comment: Thank you! This is actually my first post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way to turn this around is to ask: how do you go about finding what you need? What would you like the optimal experience to be? And how have similar products/solutions been modeled?

There are two ways in which someone likes to find what they're looking for: with **conversational** queries, and **relational** queries.

[Reuters](https://reuters.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) and [Zoosk](https://help.zoosk.com/hc/en-us) are great examples of this.

[image]

They have a large search bar where they can type in whatever they like, for example "*how can I eat all the pancakes*?", and then the site will try to match that query in an intelligent way. That is a **conversational** query. Below this search bar are buttons that will allow to user to drill-down and navigate towards what they need, forming a **relational** query: Eating -> Breakfast -> pancakes -> all the pancakes

Woah, that sounds like a lot, eh? But implementing this into your design is easy. Simply provide two things: **text search** and **filters**

A popular example of this is the jQuery plugin [datatable](https://datatables.net/).

[image]

The user can look at your big, spooky grid and either type in exactly what they want, or they can sort and filter until they discover what they need. Allowing those two methods to coexist in your UI will result in happy users, which ought to result in a happy you.

Just to add a bit more: something that my silly brain felt went without saying but might better address the question is the feature of **automatic filtering** and how to best implement in. The always-magnificent nngroug has [a great article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/applying-filters/) on that exact subject.

To summarize their article a bit, what they've found is that it is difficult to accurately predict users’ mindset while they are filtering, so employ the following:

- Let users tell you when they’re done selecting filters.
- Detect activity around the filters. (if the mouse leaves the filter area and moves to main results, it’s a good sign that users are ready for the results)
- Update results based on the time since the last selection.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a very similar design I worked on before.
Three ways to make it easier for the user to get to the record required:

1- Add **Sorting**, it always comes in handy to provide the user with sorting options.

2- **Filters!** Think of the most useful filters that users would need.

3- Provide **Search** text-field that responds on the fly while user is typing (i.e. If user has typed "Can" display only the records that have "Can" text in them).

Hope this helps!

[image]